# Where clause on date, hour & minute

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a table.

```
userId|date      |hour|minute|five|four|three|two|one|
------+----------+----+------+----+----+-----+---+---+
dinesh|2021-05-28|   6|     5|   0|   1|    0|  0|  0|
jay   |2021-05-29|   1|    20|   1|   0|    1|  0|  0|
```

How can filter date, hour & minute between a given range.
Suppose I want all the entries from 2021-05-28 05:00 to 2021-05-29 23:59

I will be performing some aggregate queries such as

```
select userId, date, sum(five) as five, sum(four) as four
from table where <2021-05-28 05:00 to 2021-05-29 23:59> group by userId, date
```

Comment: This will be significantly easier if you store the date and time in a `timestamp` type instead of three separate columns.

Comment: This is an aggregated table by minute. 
If i store by timestamp then it will be by second which we don't want

Comment: what datatype of column `date`? is it date or string?

Comment: it is date for now, we can change it to string also. Its a columnar db.

Comment: @DineshGowda you can store rounded minutes in a timestamp type, no need for seconds to get involved.

Comment: @BlueStar can u share some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below for BigQuery standard SQL (assuming `date` column is of date datatype)

```
select userId, date, sum(five) as five, sum(four) as four
from your_table
where datetime(date, time(hour, minute, 0)) 
between datetime('2021-05-28 05:00:00') and datetime('2021-05-29 23:59:59')
group by userId, date
```

Comment: just curious what would be the answer if date is string type?

Comment: you would use `where datetime(parse_date('%F', date), time(hour, minute, 0)) between ...` instead

Answer (score 1):

Since you're essentially storing a timestamp and are trying to do timestamp operations with it, I recommend using a `timestamp` type. Your data would then look something like this:

```
 userid |      timestamp      | five | four | three | two | one
--------+---------------------+------+------+-------+-----+-----
 dinesh | 2021-05-28 06:05:00 |    0 |    1 |     0 |   0 |   0
 jay    | 2021-05-29 01:20:00 |    1 |    0 |     1 |   0 |   0
```

And you could query like this:

```sql
select userId, timestamp::date, sum(five) as five, sum(four) as four
from your_table
where timestamp between '2021-05-28 05:00:00' and '2021-05-29 23:59:59'
group by userId, timestamp::date
```

Comment: How would i round off to nearest minute on timestamp field in the basetable?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but there's a `date_trunc` function for truncating all of the seconds you don't care about: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC